# How to relate a derivative in tortoise coordinates with the radial coordinate?

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, derivatives

Since the radial coordinate and the tortoise coordinate are related by

`r* = r + 2M Log (r/2M-1)`

How can I write the derivative `dF/dr*` and `d²F/dr*²`?

Can they also be written in terms of the lambda(r) and/or nu(r) background functions?

Comment: This is a question about calculus, not physics.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule